# amazon s3 The specified key does not exist after get_key success

Tags: python, web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

I am using python and boto

this is my code:

```
key = bucket.get_key(key_name)
if not key:
    print 'error, key does not exist'
    return
data = key.get_contents_as_string()
```

sometimes (appears randomly) i get this exception:

> S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 404 Not Found

NOTE: the file is uploaded by one server and then immediately afterwards another server (located in a different continent) is running the code above.

the traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/test.py", line 222, in _process_response
>
> data = key.get_contents_as_string()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.1.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py",
>
> line 1201, in get_contents_as_string
>       response_headers=response_headers)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.1.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py",
>
> line 1093, in get_contents_to_file
>       response_headers=response_headers)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.1.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py",
>
> line 996, in get_file
>       override_num_retries=override_num_retries)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.1.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py",
>
> line 211, in open
>       override_num_retries=override_num_retries)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.1.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py",
>
> line 165, in open_read
>       self.resp.reason, body) S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 404 Not Found
>
> `NoSuchKey`The specified key does not
>   exist.key_nameidhost_id

so i get the key but then when i try and read from it i get 'not found'. 
any idea ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, according to [Amazon S3 developer guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyMode):

> ... However, information about the changes might not immediately replicate across Amazon S3 and you might observe the following behaviors: A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and immediately attempts to read it. Until the change is fully propagated, Amazon S3 might report "key does not exist."